# Custom Umlaut mappings for Gnome/Wayland (xmodmap alternative)

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard-layout, wayland, xkb

Under X11 I used the following `.Xmodmap` to easily type Umlauts on a US keyboard layout:

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch Alt_R
keycode 39 = s S ssharp
keycode 38 = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode 30 = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode 32 = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
```

But this does not work when switching from X11 to Wayland. From what I read so far, a corresponding xkb configuration in `~/.config/xkb/symbols/us-german-umlaut` would look like

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
    include "us(altgr-intl)"
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
    name[Group1] = "English (US, international with German umlaut)";
    key <AD03> { [ e, E, EuroSign, cent ] };
    key <AD07> { [ u, U, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
    key <AD09> { [ o, O, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };
    key <AC01> { [ a, A, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
    key <AC02> { [ s, S, ssharp ] };
};
```

Is this the right way to go? How do I actually enable this using Gnome 43.4?

There is [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521136/key-remapping-for-special-characters-umlauts-in-wayland), but that one is specific to Sway.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/936 also looks related, but I could not make that approach work, either.